# How to set name of class in .yml in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I have an_errors.html.erb that takes an object and has

```
<%= object.class.name %>.
```

It is called by this in a _form.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', object: @product %>
```

What should I write in my xx.yml file to find the translation?

I have

```
models:
  product: Produkt
```

which doesn't do the job.

Any clues?

Cheers Carl

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you are going after, however, the following might work.

In your YAML file:

```
models: 
  product: 'Product'
```

In your ERB view:

```
# The following assumes "object" in your original post relates to the string (Product) in the YAML file 
<%= object.constantize %> # this outputs the details of your class 
<%= object.constantize.to_s %> # would be a string representation of your class (i.e., 'Product')
```

[API docs for Constantize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize)

Again, was not 100% sure what you were looking to accomplish but wanted to offer the suggestion in the event it helps!

Comment: I made some clarifications. 'object' is an object of the Product class. <%= object.class.name.constantize %> gives me 'Product', but not my translated version.